# React Hook Form Property 'type' is missing in type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' but required in type 'FieldError'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-hook-form, yup

I'm building an Next.js application using TypeScript, TailwindCSS, ReactHookForm and Yup.

Everything is working fine, it validates, throws and displays the error as expected, but I'm getting a typing error when using ReactHookForm to throw errors and passing them to my Input component.

My code:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(signUpFormSchema) });

  return (
    <>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitSignUpForm)}
          className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-4 px-4 py-6 rounded-md group bg-gray-150"
        >
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-wide uppercase text-blue">
            Inputs
          </h1>

          <Input
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Seu nome Completo"
            label={
              <>
                Seu <strong>Nome</strong>
              </>
            }
            error={errors.name}
            {...(register('name'),
            {
              onChange: (e) => {
                setValue('name', maskName(e.target.value));
              }
            })}
          />

          <Button type="submit">Enviar</Button>
        </form>
    </>
  );
```

Here's my Input component:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { FieldError } from 'react-hook-form';

import { CheckIcon } from 'assets/Icons';

import styles from './styles.module.css';

type InputProps = {
  variant?: 'default' | 'search';
  name: string;
  label?: React.ReactNode;
  error?: FieldError;
} & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const VariantMap = {
  default: styles.default,
  search: styles.search
};

const InputBase: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<
  HTMLInputElement,
  InputProps
> = ({ variant = 'default', name, label, error = null, ...rest }, ref) => {
  const defaultClassName = styles.root;
  const className = [defaultClassName, VariantMap[variant]];

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full gap-1.25 relative">
      {label && (
        <label htmlFor={name} className={styles.label}>
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
      <input
        name={name}
        id={name}
        ref={ref}
        {...rest}
        className={className.join(' ')}
      />
      <CheckIcon className="absolute transform translate-y-1/2 bottom-6 right-5" />
      {!!error && <span>{error.message}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

export const Input = forwardRef(InputBase);
```

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be an issue with `react-hook-form` types. Since you already have a custom implementation of a Input component I would recommend using [useController](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller) to fetch the field error instead of getting it through the errors object from `useForm`.

To use that hook, all you have to do is send an object with field registered name and react-hook-form's controller. Doing that your error attribute will have the correct `FieldError | undefined` type.

```js
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form'

function TextField({ label, controller }) {
  const { fieldState: { error } } = useController({ name, controller })
  ...
}
```

btw, you omit the controller if you're already using [FormProvider](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance)